# Output is saying the img element does not exist (is null), but script is below implementation of img and onload() is used

Tags: javascript, html

I've been through all the questions on here that have to do with the **"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src**(innerHTML, etc.)**' of null"** Error, which all of them say to:

**1.** Move the script tags below all the html code (which I've done), and

**2.** Wrap all javascript text inside the onload event handler, which i have also done to the best of my knowledge.

So, my question... why am i getting "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'src' of null"?

Thank you in advance

```
    <html>
<head>
    <title>Lab 8</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <style>
        div{
            text-align: center;
        }
        img{
            margin-left: auto; 
            margin-right: auto; 
            width: 900px; 
            height: 500px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <img src="images/sailboat.jpg" alt="sailboat" id="sailboatImg">
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.addEventListener("load", function() {

            var i = 0;

            function clickHandler (event){
                i += 1;
                if (i == 1){
                    document.getElementById(sailboatImg).src = "images/i14.jpg";
                }else if(i == 2){
                    document.getElementById(sailboatImg).src = "images/c&c.png";
                }else if (i == 3){
                    document.getElementById(sailboatImg).sec = "images/420.jpg";
                }
            }

            document.getElementById("sailboatImg").addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed quotes: `"`inside `clickHandler`:

```
function clickHandler (event){
    i += 1;
    if (i == 1){
        document.getElementById("sailboatImg").src = "images/i14.jpg";
 //--------------------------------------^these
   }else if(i == 2){
       document.getElementById("sailboatImg").src = "images/c&c.png";
   }else if (i == 3){
       document.getElementById("sailboatImg").src = "images/420.jpg";
   }
}
```

By the way it's better to cache the reference to `<img>` than querying it over and over:

```
window.addEventListener("load", function() {

  var i = 0;
  var img = document.getElementById("sailboatImg");
  function clickHandler(event) {
    i += 1;
    if (i == 1) {
      img.src = "images/i14.jpg";
    } else if (i == 2) {
      img.src = "images/c&c.png";
    } else if (i == 3) {
      img.src = "images/420.jpg";
    }
  }

  img.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);
});
```

Comment: Or just `sailboatImg.src` as `id` becomes `key` of the `window` object and it holds the element..